# Firestore .setData is blocked by update rule not create

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swift4, firebase-security

I found someone with a similar issue here [Firebase Firestore .set is updating instead of creating (skipping rules)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50922146/firebase-firestore-set-is-updating-instead-of-creating-skipping-rules) and no answers.

I have a security rule that allows anyone to create a document at a path but only allows owners to edit an already existing doc.  The update security rule is blocking the create.  I'm guessing I'm having some misunderstanding as to how the rules work.  If I remove the update rules every works fine.

```
  match /users_real/{userID} {
    allow create: if true;
    allow read: if isOwner(userID);
    allow update: if ((request.writeFields.size() == 1) && 
    (('ptypes' in request.writeFields) || ('ptypes' in request.writeFields))  && isOwner(userID));           
  }
```

set data:

```
self.docRef.collection("users_real").document("adfadsf").setData(post) { (error) in

            if let error = error {
                print("He dead!: \(error.localizedDescription)")


            }
            else {
                print("it worked, for now")


            }
        }
```

Comment: If I am not mistaking, your current rules does not "only allows owners to edit an already existing doc"

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: YOur update rule is as follows: `if ((request.writeFields.size() == 1) && (('ptypes' in request.writeFields) || ('ptypes' in request.writeFields)));`  . there is no reference to any owner in it.

Comment: You're correct my mistake put the wrong edit up, took a few edits locate the issue.  That difference doesn't effect my overall question tho because on create, the update rule shouldn't come into play at all.

Comment: So while you're correct I believe its irrelevant

Comment: Also I noticed you edit the question I linked to that no one has answered, do you have any insight into the issue?