# Firestore Security Rules breaking with update rule

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I posted a question about this yesterday but I'm creating a new one with more details.
[Firestore .setData is blocked by update rule not create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51622043/firestore-setdata-is-blocked-by-update-rule-not-create?noredirect=1#comment90210244_51622043)

I've run the simulator and the rules work there.  Also when I create the document and change `setData` in the swift code to `update` the code works.  It appears to only fail when creating the document.  But the catch is that when I remove the `update` rule or simply change it to `allow update: if false;`  the setData (or seen as create by the rules) executes properly.  I have no clue whats going on nor do I know of any tools for getting a better insight.

```
 match /users_real/{userID} {
    allow create: if true;
    allow read: if isOwner(userID);
    allow update: if (request.writeFields.size() == 1);
```

}

set data:

```
self.docRef.collection("users_real").document("adfadsf").setData(post) { (error) in

            if let error = error {
                print("He dead!: \(error.localizedDescription)")


            }
            else {
                print("it worked, for now")


            }
        }
```

Comment: [The documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations) indicates the `create` rule is applied when the document does _not_ exist and the `update` rule is applied when the document _does_ exist. The implication is that document existence is the determinant, not the type of operation (`setData()` or `updateData()`.  Are you saying that you see different behavior when, for the same DB state, you change `setData()` to `updateData()`?

Comment: No,  what I am seeing is that for the db state setData() the permissions succeed or fail depending on the 'allow update' rule (which doesn't make sense) when in practice (simulator works fine).  I also observed that when I am actually updating (updateData) the security rules are invoked properly and things pass when they should.  It is only particular update rules on setData that are failing (those particular rules are in the question).

Comment: The posted code uses `setData()`.  If document "adfadsf" does not exist, the `create` rule is used.  If "adfadsf" _does_ exist. the `update` rule is used.  `updateData()` can only be used on an existing document ([it will fail if the doc does not exist](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentReference#updatedata_)), so the `update` rule is always used.

Comment: But that’s why I’m so confused.  When I run the simulation, create passes and indicates the create rule.  But in practice it fails only when the update rule is present.  Do you know of a way to get more info from the db side about the security rules (maybe similar to the logs for cloud functions)?

Comment: Your update rule has an extra `(`.  Is that just a typo in your post?

Comment: yes its a typo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177214/discussion-between-blue-and-bob-snyder).

Comment: After more tests, I am able to reproduce your results.  Pretty sure it's a bug.  Suggest you file a problem report: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time.

Comment: It appears the problem may be specific to use of `request.writeFields`.  Other conditions seem to work.  The other [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50922146/4815718) also uses `writeFields`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Support confirms that there is a bug related to the evaluation of `request.writeFields.size()`. No estimate was given of when it will be fixed.

The existence of the bug can be demonstrated with the following rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /cities/{city} {
      // This should always evaluate to true, but does not.
      allow create: if (request.writeFields.size() == 1) || (request.writeFields.size() != 1);
      allow update: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Although the `create` rule should always evaluate to true, an attempt to create a city fails with Permission Denied.  It seems that the problem with `request.writeFields` affects not only the rule in which it appears, but also other rules for the path.  For the rules shown above, an attempt to update an existing city also fails with Permission Denied.